# How to get <input> to take a single file from a directory upload?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, input

I've linked a React button to my html input tag so that it takes a file for upload. This works, I'm able to specify a file from a directory and made it to where it will only accept a certain type of file so that's good. What I'm wanting to do is to upload a whole directory and select only that file from the directory. The closest I can find a solution to this is by using webkitdirectory, but it keeps running into issues with Typescript and I think it may also be an issue with React. This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
    fileRef = React.createRef<any>();
    <Button> 
       content="Choose File" 
       icon="file" 
       onClick={() => this.fileRef.current.click()} 
    />
    <input 
       id="filepicker" 
       type="file" 
       ref={this.fileRef} 
       onChange={this.fileChange} 
       multiple= {true} 
       hidden={true} 
       accept=".mp4" 
     />
```

What do I need to add in order to get my html input tag to take multiple directories at once and only upload an .mp4 file from each directory?

Comment: for this.fileChange, all this does is take the file and uploads it to a database. This runs sucessfully and has no issues with the compiler.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to ask is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615830/equivalent-to-directory-mozdirectory-and-webkitdirectory-in-react